# how to create method with same name of system function?

Tags: c++, function, sockets, methods, listen

I'm new to c++ and have to create class for handling sockets.
This class has a method named listen() and in this method need calling listen function to socket (for example see below) but method listen hiding listen function how to solve it ?

```
void CTCPBlockingSocket::listen() {
     listen(server_socket,5); 
}
```

Comment: It's generally bad practice to do this if the already defined method is contained in global scope...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `::` operator to specify you want the `listen` name which is in the global scope, not in a class or namespace.

```
void CTCPBlockingSocket::listen() {
     ::listen(server_socket,5); 
}
```